# how to solve Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'm using RN 0.46.0 and after setup the login component i'm trying to use the navigator to push another component. but shows this

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

When i click at the button

Even the docs just have this way to get another component.

Someone know if this is related to the version?

Or for Navigation need to create a route?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text,  View, Navigator, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';
import Signup from './Signup';

class Login extends Component {



     goToSignup(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Signup
    });
  }




    render() {


        return(

            <Card>            

            <CardSection>

            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
            <Input

            placeholder="Email"
            />

            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
            <Input
            secureTextEntry

            placeholder="Password"
            />


            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>

            <Button>
            Log In
            </Button>        
            </CardSection>   
            <CardSection>

   <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.goToSignup.bind(this)}>

<Text >
    Go to Sign up
      </Text>       


    </TouchableHighlight>


</CardSection>


</Card>





);

}


}



export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-Native v0.46 doesn't have the `Navigator` component. It has been removed since v0.44. You have to use other navigation solutions.

[React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) ( Recommended, created by the react community )

Other 3rd party solutions:

[React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/)

[Native Navigation](http://airbnb.io/native-navigation/)

Comment: I think Wix navigator is better, at least it's recommended by Airbnb.
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation

Comment: Thank you very much @shubhniksingh

Answer (score 0):

here this.props.navigator is undefined make sure this.props.navigator is available to avoid this error you can put one check

```
goToSignup(){
 if(typeof this.props.navigator !== "undefined"){
   this.props.navigator.push({
             component: Signup
   });
  }
 }
```